# Prime failed ('nope'); will stop (1/5925 frames)

Tags: ios, audioqueue

When started the audioqueue work well, it can playback audio, but when I manually change the progess of  player, AudioQueuePrime will fail ,output Prime failed ('nope'); will stop (1/5925 frames), the errorcode returned is 1852797029, but next AudioQueueStart will succeed, and so the player will work, then just AudioQueuePrime failed sometimes. So why?